# jquery/css image clipping

Tags: jquery, css

What I want:

Clip images with different sizes and resolutions into square,
whose width is variable that depends on the grid system.
Images are middle-centered both vertically and horizontally.

My method:

Using `overflow:hidden;` and css positioning to make masks.

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img/>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    img {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

js (jQuery):

```
function imgClip() {
    $wrapperWidth = $(".wrapper").width();
    $(".wrapper").height($wrapperWidth);

    $(".wrapper img").each(function() {

        $img = $(this);

        if ($img.width() >= $img.height()) {        
            $img.height($wrapperWidth);
            $img.css('left', ($img.width()-$wrapperWidth)/2*(-1));
        }
        else {
            $img.width($wrapperWidth);
            $img.css('top', ($img.height()-$wrapperWidth)/2*(-1));
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(imgClip);
$(window).resize(imgClip);
```

Most of the time it works, however sometimes it breaks and looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hKaw.jpg).

1. The offset is incorrect by 50% of the width of wrapper
2. Not all of the images is incorrect
3. Fixed when reload the page or resize the window

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not what you're looking for but you could consider using background-images?

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```